# how to input 5 element in array and print sum of elements

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to add 5 element in array and print sum of elements  in java script without function

```html
  <HTML>
    <body>
         <script type="text/javascript">
      var x=new Array(5);
      for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
     x[i]=prompt("enter Any Value") <!-- its properly working till now -->
      
      t=0;
      for(t+= x[i];) 
       
      for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
      document.write(x[i]);
      }
      </script>
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: `for(t+= x[i];) `?? You seem to understand how `for` loops work, so what made you think this is the way to sum the elements of an array?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try

```
var sum=0;
var times = 5;
for(i=0;i<times;i++){
   sum+=parseInt(prompt("enter Any Value"));
}
console.log(sum);
document.write(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <HTML>
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var x=new Array(5);
     t=0;
     for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        x[i]=prompt("enter Any Value") <!-- its properly working till now -->
        t+= x[i]; 
     }
     document.write(t);
     </script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Corrected your code:

```
<HTML>
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     var x = new Array(5);
     var sum = 0;

     for(i=0;i < x.length;i++){
        x[i] = parseInt(prompt("enter Any Value")); <!-- its properly working till now -->
        sum += x[i];
    }
    alert("Sum is: " + sum);


     </script>
</body>
```